# For Locale other than english, themes does not get applied

Tags: theme, store-view, template-directive

I was having a configuration where the setup was like below

```
Main Website
     ---->Store 1(store for XYZ sister company)
          ----> English Store View
     ---->Store 2(store for ABC sister company)
          ----> English Store View
     ---->Store 3(store for LMN sister company)
          ----> English Store View
```

And I have a custom theme, which is getting applied properly for all the store views.

But, recently, my client wanted three other store views for each store. Namely, german, french and dutch. Accordingly I created the store views and my current setup looks like this:

```
Main Website
     ---->Store 1(store for XYZ sister company)
          ----> English Store View
          ----> German Store View
          ----> French Store View
          ----> Dutch Store View
     ---->Store 2(store for ABC sister company)
          ----> English Store View
          ----> German Store View
          ----> French Store View
          ----> Dutch Store View
     ---->Store 3(store for LMN sister company)
          ----> English Store View
          ----> German Store View
          ----> French Store View
          ----> Dutch Store View
```

The custom theme is getting applied only for the english store view, but not the other ones. i.e., for german, french and dutch store views.

I have already checked in System->Configuration->Web , System->Configuration->General and System->Configuration->Design for the working ones as well as the non working ones, both are looking same.

Further, when I investigated, The template i,e., all the phtml files were being pulled from rwd/default instead of rwd/custom_theme, (custom_theme is the theme which I am using).

I tried adding the template path rwd/custom_theme for Templates, Skin (Images / CSS) and Layout in System->Configuration->Design for the german storeview of XYZ company. The page loads with no js and css. And the template i,e., all the phtml files were loaded from base/default, this time.

So I renamed the rwd/default to rwd/default_old and Copied rwd/custom_theme to rwd/default. And It started working. I am sure this is not the right way to do this.

Your help is highly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, By going to System->Design and "Add Design Change"(setting the rwd/custom_theme) to all the store views that I had created newly.